# Functional Form of this curve

Tags: functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions, functional-equations

I'm trying to describe this graph in a functional form. My apologies for the quality of the drawing. It is meant to be a depiction of a sine wave which reaches its maxima, the gradient of the graph then goes to $0$ for a period of $x$ equal to that of the domain of the sine wave. It then increases by the sine wave again and this process repeats itself throughout the function domain.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For example, $\,f(x)=x-\sin(x)\,$ is monotonically increasing, with inflection points at $\,x=2k\pi\,$.

[image]